# Why does for-comprehension reverse the input list?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, for-comprehension

I have written this scala code:

```
scala> val lists = List(1, 2, 3) :: List.empty :: List(5, 2) :: Nil
lists: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(), List(5, 2))

scala> val x = for {
     | list @ head :: _ <- lists
     | } yield list.size
x: List[Int] = List(3, 2)
```

this works but the output is a big confusing. How did the list get reversed?

I was hoping that the output `list @ head` would mean `List(1, 2) :: 3`

but the output of List(3, 2) is a little unexplained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list isn't reversed, you're returning a list that contains the sizes of the other lists. Your for-comprehension is roughly equivalent to this:

```
lists.collect { case list @ head :: _ => list.size }
```

`list @ head :: _` matches only non-empty lists, and the `list` identifier is the entire `List` being mapped--which is getting mapped to its size. So the list of sizes would be `List(3, 0, 2, 0)`, which is `List(3, 2)` when the empty lists are discarded.